# Trying to fetch all transactions containing specific type for a certain TRON address using trongrid

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb, tronlink

I am using api.trongrid.io to fetch transactions for a TRON address and this works 100%, however, is it possible to fetch all transactions for this TRON address that contains a specific type?

Has anyone perhaps managed to find a way to do this?

I have already searched all possible answers and also checked Documentation but yet no result.